# fileScan.nextLine() comes back with a "cannot find symbol" error

Tags: java

**EDIT:** Foolish mistake. nextLine is the solution. Thanks again @mellamokb

Trying to run an example from a Java book, but I'm getting a compiling error. The code is as follows:

```
public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException
{
    String url;
    Scanner fileScan, urlScan;

    fileScan = new Scanner(new File("websites.inp"));

    // Read and process each line of the file

    while (fileScan.hasNext())
    {
        url = fileScan.nextline();
        System.out.println("URL: " + url);

        urlScan = new Scanner(url);
        urlScan.useDelimiter("/");

        // Print each part of the url

        while (urlScan.hasNext())
            System.out.println(" " + urlScan.next());
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

The error reads:

```
URLDissector.java:26: cannot find symbol  
symbol  : method nextline()
location: class java.util.Scanner
                    url = fileScan.nextline();
                                  ^
```

I thought the problem was the fact that I don't have a "websites.inp" file that it may need to reference, so I created one (though I simply saved the filename as "websites.inp" but it's saved as a txt, not sure how to adjust that)

I've had a similar problem where I tried initializing DecimalFormat before with "new," but this time I'm apparently supposed to use that. So not sure where the problem lies.

Thanks

Comment: You have a typo in the method name.  It's [`nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()), with a capital `L`.

Comment: @mellamokb I honestly thought I checked every letter. New at this coding thing. Thought I had it down this time =[ lol thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Scanner` does not have a method named `nextline()`, although it does have one named [`nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29). Method names (among other things) are case-sensitive in Java.